# Figuring out total height of a div

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to make a simple vertical slider on my website. With this simple code

```
$('.down').click(function(){
    $('#container_slider_youtube').animate({ marginTop: '-=410px'}, 1000);
});

$('.up').click(function(){
    $('#container_slider_youtube').animate({ marginTop: '+=410px'}, 1000);
});
```

I can slide my container with everything in it up and down which works fine. But a problem I'm having is that you can keep pressing the up or down button which totally messes up the position of the div. So what's a good way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Might probably be better not to rely on relative values, and instead, compute for new, static values to assign to `.animate()`.

Also, for applications such as this, I find that it's way more simpler to use CSS `position` and `top` instead of relying on `margin`. Some (older) browsers seem to have a hate for negative margins that burn with the fire of a thousand hells.

```
// example
var container = $('#container_slider_youtube'),
    parent = container.parent(),
    step = 410
    ;
$('.down').click(function () {

    var currentTop = container.css('top'),
        newTop = Math.max(0, currentTop - step)
        ;

    container.animate({ marginTop : newTop }, 1000);

});
```

You can adapt this for the `.up` click. Make sure you account for the height of the container parent (using `.height()` most probably).

If you're going to go the CSS `position` route, make sure that the container parent is *at least* `position:relative`, and that the container is *at least* the same as well. I personally set the container to `position:absolute`.